# Registering generic components in Windsor.Castle: difference in behavior between Type.GetType and typeof

Tags: c#, .net, generics, castle-windsor

I'm testing Windsor.Castle for the resolving of my generic components.

I'm configuring my container with lines like the following:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ICommand<,>)).ImplementedBy(Type.GetType("WCExp.Test.GetAllCommand`2")).Named("GetAllCommand"));
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ICommand<,>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(WindsorCastleExperiments.Implementations.GetAllCommand<,>)).Named("GetAllCommandOriginal"));
```

As you can see ImplementedBy is provided a Type, either through   Type.GetType() or through typeof().

Now while I was testing, I noticed that sometimes the registrated service was not the implementing class, but the interface .

Error message:Error creating instance  ICommand...  is abstract. ( left out full type string)

Is it possible that when using Type.GetType() can sometimes return a interface for a given type string, even if the given type string is the class type definition?

Thus can

```
Type.GetType("WCExp.Test.GetAllCommand`2")
```

return the interface  ICommand<,>...?

This was happening for the classes that were residing in a dependent assembly.
For classes in the same assembly as I was configuring this problem didn't present itself (yet?)

Full sources: https://github.com/schwarzie2478/WindsorCastleExperiments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.  In the end it had nothing to do with Castle. ( But Castle allows it to happen ): )

Type.GetType expects a type string that **includes the assemblyName** for types that exist outside of the currently running assembly.

But because I never checked to see what this function returned, I didn't know the registration was happening against a null value, which Castle allows, but then the interface is registered as the service instead of an implementation as I expected...